# rJava on Mac: Error loading from library: unable to find JVM

Tags: r, rjava

I can install rJava seemingly fine from Rstudio:

```
 install.packages("rJava")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/rJava_1.0-6.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1138672 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/qz/9s5hs9ss00z2yzj_r2668_3c0000gn/T//RtmpqNOAbP/downloaded_packages
```

But when I then try to call it from the library I get the following error:

```
library(rJava)
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JVM could not be found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)
> library(rJava)
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JVM could not be found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)
```

I have installed the latest version of Java and my R is version 4.1.2. I'm using Mac.

If anyone knows how to help I would be very grateful.

Thank you!